# Directory with colon in PATH variable

Tags: linux, shell, path

Linux allows `:` character in file (or directory) names. Can a directory containing `:` in its name be added to shell `PATH` variable without screwing up `PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

According to POSIX specification:

> The prefixes shall be separated by a colon ( ':' )

Then, if you add a directory with `<colon>` to `PATH` It'll interpreted like a different path and sure you'll get a error.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03